# 1MB worth of drop-down list data, needs to be downloaded and displayed dynamically

Tags: html, dynamic, drop-down-menu

So I've got a website with two HTML drop-down lists- one is a list of US states, the other is a list of the cities/towns in the selected state.  As of right now, I have a file for each state, and they all have the options listed as such:

```
<option value="44.729932, -72.381758">Albany</option>
<option value="44.976728, -73.30257">Alburg</option>
```

The value is the city/town's coordinates.  I can't have all this data downloaded at once (well I guess I could but it's 1MB and I'm serving the page on a 130KB/s connection...) so I'd like a way to have each town/city file downloaded once its state name has been selected... I made these files under the assumption I could just do this:

```
<select name="state" method="get" id="state">
     <option value="citiestowns/alabama.html">Alabama</option>
     <option value="citiestowns/alaska.html">Alaska</option>
</select>
<select id="cityortown" name="cityortown">
<?php
$state = $_GET['state'];

include("$state");
?>
</select>
```

But when I do this, I just get the state drop down list and a blank drop down list next to it... heeeeeelp! :(

Comment: FYI, the `$_GET['state']` is never assigned because the form needs to be submitted for it to interact with the server. You should have a read up on [AJAX techniques](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/) to learn how to do requests without reloading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use AJAX for this.  Thats a technique using PHP and Javascript that allows your page to get new data from the server without a page reload.  This will allow your page to initally get only the states from a server and then get the relevant cities and their data from a PHP script.

So you're going to need

1. First HTML page.  Can be static or PHP generated, but will need some javascript so that once a state is selected from the states drop-down the city drop down will be generated.

   a- The original HTML page with state drop down

   b- The javascript described above
2. A PHP script.  This page will never be gone to 'directly' (you wouldnt type its URL into your browser most likely), but it will be the target of a server request.

   Input - Parameter indicating which state

   Output - The dropdown with the cities belonging to that state and their values.

---

You don't state what form your data is in (im guessinng/hoping a relational DB?  Document DB wouldnt be bad, but CSV would be pretty tough) but ill try to paint a rough sketch of the PHP script I describe in step 2.

getcities.php

```
<?php

$state = $_GET['state'];
$cityArray = getCityArray($state); //i won't delve into details here, but probably takes some database calls

echo "<select name='citySelect'>";
foreach($cityArray as $cur)
{
    list($x,$y,$name) = array($cur['x'].$cur['y'],$cur['name']); //this is just to make the next line simpler.  PHP extract function can do something similar too
    echo "<option value='$x,$y'>$name</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

You can see how this generates the select/option dropdown with only the required elements.

The javascript will be responsibly for calling something like `getcities.php?state='NY'` and putting the output into an element of your page (likely a div)

Look up Ajax basics for how to do that.  Libraries like jQuery can greatly simplify the Ajax.

---

EDIT - in response to your comments

So on your page you can do something like

```
<select name='state' id='stateSelect' onchange='loadCities()'>
    <option value='' select='selected'>Please select a state</option>
    <option value='alabama.html'>Alabama</option>
    OPTIONS FOR EACH STATE HERE
</selecT>

<select name='city' id='citySelect'> //blank initially.  gets filled when you pick a state
</select>

<script type='text/javascript'>

  function loadCities()
  {
    $('#citySelect').load($('#stateSelect').val()); //this assumes files in same place.  otherwise you might need to put a path here
  }
</script>
```

Basically, if the format is as you describe, all you need to do is load the contents of a certain HTML file into the `<select>` i call `citySelect` above.  This can be done entirely by javascript, and with the use of the jQuery library it is pretty much trivial.

Comment: All the data is actually just in HTML files :/  I guess I can find a way to put it in a database if that's necessary...

Comment: no thats fine, but what do you mean 'in HTML files'  like they are already set up in `option` tags?  what associates them with the appropriate states?

Comment: Yeah... so for instance, Virginia's file just has several lines that are simply: <option value="coordinatesfortown">TownName</option>... the only thing associating Virginia's file with the state of Virginia is the filename (virginia.html), and my thinking was that the value for Virginia in the States dropdown could be virginia.html

Comment: this might not be the most extensible design, but it will actually make the problem at hand pretty simple, and can be done entirely with javascript (no need for extra php file like i mentioned)

Comment: @tyler you were thinking right about those values.  check out my edit.  the autocomplete some of the other guys mentioned isnt a bad idea, but i dont see it being necessary unless the amount of choices is much bigger than im thinking (in the hundreds).

Comment: Thanks sooo much for that!  I feel stupid saying this but I don't know what you mean by "all you need to do is load the contents of a certain HTML file into the <select> i call citySelect above. This can be done entirely by javascript. This can be done entirely by javascript, and with the use of the jQuery library it is pretty much trivial"... I don't know enough Javascript to write things on my own yet :(  I'm gonna be researching jQuery all night but I feel like this is maybe easy for you to expand upon for me?  If you want to... you've already done so much! (awesome community!)

Comment: not really sure what youre asking for.  you tried what i posted and it worked for you, but you want to understand it better?  or you cant get it together, having trouble with jQuery?

Comment: Sorry, I got your code working and I was super excited, it passes the coordinates on as the value for "city" and everything, but... This is all going into SimpleGeo via their PHP script, so I copied the $q = _GET['q'] thing (I know that's probably not quite right, I'm away from my comp) which was used to include the text field 'q' in the search.  Thing is, I think SimpleGeo might require that it be in the form of "$lat, $lon", so could I do something like splitting the coordinates into something like lat="85.85478" and lon="84.886643" instead of just value="COORDINATES", then pass those things

Comment: ... on to the PHP script you wrote for me... I don't know if this is possible though, and I certainly don't know how :(

Comment: that `getcities.php` was before you described how you had all those separate html files.  its one or the other, not both

Comment: Oh I see what you're thinking :P  When I mentioned the SimpleGeo PHP script, I meant the one they provide as part of their API... it looks like this: https://gist.github.com/raw/760327/6ab784948e79e8dcc2fc640bf5ed3f74a7d84b08/simplegeo-places-search-args.php
Now how would I make $lat and $lon equal the values in the HTML files?  I have no problem modifying the existing city files but I don't know how I'm supposed to change them, nor do I know how to refer to the lats and lons once they've been separated...  Hopefully this is the last time I need to bug you :P

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you need to show the proper city based on a previously selected state?

Why not use a auto-complete (jQueryUI for instance). And your PHP back-end would parse your data (PHP will not send that 1MB down to the user, as it is done server side).

In this fashion you are returning at most 10 results (as a user types their city name).  A drop down is inefficient for such a large data set.  A search / auto-complete method will function much better IMHO.

Reference:

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: Does something like jQueryUI work flawlessly on IE6?  I appreciate the suggestion, I'm just not sure I have the skills to implement something like jQueryUI :(  I'll check it out though... I'm anxious to get a version of this running even if it's less convenient than an auto-complete, so if anyone has a way to do this similar to how I was originally trying to set it up, let me know! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what's happening in the rest of your setup, it looks like your attempting to have a set of files on the server, one for each state, that contains all the select options for that state.  Is this correct?  It feels like a hard way to go.

Are you already using JQuery in this site?  (Or do you have any scope to use such a lib?)
You would then be able to use an autocompleter pretty easily.
See here for more details and an example : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete